# How do we change the state of element in a react component on button click in another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, react-component

I want to add the active class on an element in `componentOne` on the button click in `componentTwo`. I am using useState for it but I don't know how to pass the state into another component. The `componentTwo` is the child of the `componentOne`.

I want the active class `componentOne` as long as the button is not clicked again even when the browser loads again

Comment: Please post some code of both component so users can answer it easily

Answer (score 0):

just create a state in the parent component and pass it down as a prop

```
cosnt [active , setActive] =useState(false)

<ParentComponent>
    <componentOne active={active} , setActive={setActive} />
     <componentTwo active={active} , setActive={setActive} />
</ParentCompnent>

Component One :

  const ComponentOne = ({active}) => {
  return(
        <div className={`${active && 'activeClass'}`}></div>
   )  
 }


Component Two :

  const  ComponentTwo = ({setActive}) => {
  return(
        <button onClick={()=> setActive(true)}>
   )  
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't satisfy "even when the browser loads again"

Comment: on button click set the value to local storage and in parent component get the value from local storage to initialize the state

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).